# Marketing Cloud App Center updated documentation

Tags: marketing-cloud, appcenter

Documentation found here (https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/marketing-cloud-apps/) is out of date. Is there new documentation and where?

Answer (score 1):

This documentation is still mostly relevant, however I've authored [updated documentation here](https://github.com/mattcam/Salesforce-Marketing-Cloud-Developer-Edition-Recipes/blob/master/authentication.md). Is there anything specifically that you are looking for?